# Tamaño 0bytes al guardar imagen en Java

Tags: java, java-swing, jfilechooser, fileoutputstream

He creado una interfaz para abrir una imagen en un `jLabel` y seguidamente guardarla mediante un `jButton` en cualquier ruta del equipo/disco.

He logrado realizarlo y la guarda pero de forma incorrecta.

Si pongo el ratón encima de la imagen recién guardada me indica: **Tamaño 0 bytes.** Como vemos sale la imagen predeterminada del .png y no la miniatura de la imagen. Si hago doble click aparece la imagen, ¿pero es extraño, no?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Me da error en la línea ImageIcon fot = new ImageIcon(imagen); por tipo de conversión de dato ¿A qué se debe?**

**Código:**

```
public class GuardarImagenes extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    JFileChooser seleccionado = new JFileChooser();
    Optional<byte[]> imagen;
    FileInputStream entrada;
    FileOutputStream salida;
    File archivo;

    public GuardarImagenes() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private Optional<byte[]> readFile(String path) {
    try {
        return Optional.of(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Optional.empty();
    }

    private void button_elegirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        if(seleccionado.showDialog(null, "ABRIR ARCHIVO") == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            archivo = seleccionado.getSelectedFile();
            if(archivo.canRead()){
                if(archivo.getName().endsWith("jpg") || archivo.getName().endsWith("jpeg") || archivo.getName().endsWith("png") || archivo.getName().endsWith("gif")){
                    imagen = readFile(archivo.getAbsolutePath());
                    ImageIcon fot = new ImageIcon(imagen);
                    Icon icono = new ImageIcon(fot.getImage().getScaledInstance(label_foto.getWidth(), label_foto.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
                    label_foto.setIcon(icono);
                    button_guardar.setEnabled(true);
                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Selecionne un archivo...");
                }
            }
        }
    }                                             

    public String GuardarImagen(File archivo, Optional<byte[]> imagen) {
        String respuesta = null;
        try (FileOutputStream salida = new FileOutputStream(archivo)) {
            salida.write(imagen);
            respuesta = "La imagen se guardó con éxito.";
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return respuesta;
    }

    private void button_guardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        if(seleccionado.showDialog(null, "GUARDAR IMAGEN") == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            archivo = seleccionado.getSelectedFile();
            if(archivo.getName().endsWith("jpg") || archivo.getName().endsWith("png") || archivo.getName().endsWith("gif")){
                String respuesta = GuardarImagen(archivo, imagen);
                if (respuesta != null){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, respuesta);
                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al guardar imagen.");
                }
            }
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La imagen no tiene formato de imagen.");
        }
    }
```

**Error:**

```
run:

    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - no suitable constructor found for ImageIcon(java.util.Optional<byte[]>)
        constructor javax.swing.ImageIcon.ImageIcon(java.lang.String) is not applicable
          (argument mismatch; java.util.Optional<byte[]> cannot be converted to java.lang.String)
        constructor javax.swing.ImageIcon.ImageIcon(java.net.URL) is not applicable
          (argument mismatch; java.util.Optional<byte[]> cannot be converted to java.net.URL)
        constructor javax.swing.ImageIcon.ImageIcon(java.awt.Image) is not applicable
          (argument mismatch; java.util.Optional<byte[]> cannot be converted to java.awt.Image)
        constructor javax.swing.ImageIcon.ImageIcon(byte[]) is not applicable
          (argument mismatch; java.util.Optional<byte[]> cannot be converted to byte[])
```

Comment: Has probado cerrar el `FileOutputStream` luego de escribir?

Comment: Algunas imágenes me cargan en el Jlabel, otras me carga la mitad, otras no me cargan y se pone fondo de color gris....

Comment: Pero el problema es al guardar o al cargar? Qué versión de Java usas?

Comment: Estoy utilizando java 1.8.0_125. El problema lo tengo al "cargar" y al guardarlo en algunas fotos. No sé si la programación que hice es correcta o no. Algunas fotos no me cargan al completo, y lo que no carga lo dibuja de color gris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primer problema que tienes es en el modo con que lees/cargas el contenido del archivo de la imagen. Como la variable que usas como buffer de lectura (`byte[] imagen`) la inicializas con un tamaño fijo (`new byte[1024*100]`). Esto tiene el inconveniente de que si la imagen es más grande que ese tamaño pues habrán datos que se perderán, de ahí que se te muestre parte de la imagen en un color gris.

Para solucionar estos problemas el modo más sencillo es hacer uso del método [Files#readAllBytes()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes-java.nio.file.Path-). Es muy importante tener siempre presente de que este método debe usarse siempre y cuando el tamaño del archivo a leer no sea muy grande puesto que todo su contenido se intentará cargar en un arreglo.

```
    private Optional<byte[]> readFile(String path) {
        try {
            return Optional.of(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return Optional.empty();
    }
```

Con respecto al problema de escritura (**Tamaño 0 bytes**) la causa es que no estás cerrando el stream que usas para escribir los datos. Esto es un tema de suma importancia cuando trabajamos con archivos y debes tenerlo siempre en mente: ***"Siempre cerrar los streams luego de utilizarlos"***.

Por lo tanto una simple llama al `close()` resuelve este problema. No obstante te sugiero que uses el **try-with-resources** que cierra automáticamente todos los recuersos que declares dentro de este un vez que se salga del bloque, incluso si ocurren errores.

```
    public String GuardarImagen(File archivo, byte[] imagen) {
        String respuesta = null;
        try (FileOutputStream salida = new FileOutputStream(archivo)) {
            salida.write(imagen);
            respuesta = "La imagen se guardó con éxito.";
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return respuesta;
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación. Super entendible y clara pero... ¿y dónde estás utilizando el método readFile? ¿dónde le llamas?

Comment: Lo llamas donde mismo llamas al tuyo: `AbrirImagen()`

Comment: File cannot be converted to String... imagen = readFile(archivo);

Comment: Claro, porque si te das cuenta el método espera un `String` con la ruta al archivo. Debes hacerlo así `readFile(archivo.getAbsolutePath())`

Comment: Me aparece el mismo problema con Objet<byte[]> cannot be converted to byte[] en la línea:  ImageIcon fot = new ImageIcon(imagen);

Comment: Amigo fíjate bien en el tipo de dato que devuelve mi método: `Optional`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108394/discussion-between-omaza1990-and-e-betanzos).

Comment: Edito la pregunta para que veas también la declaración de variables. Mi tipo de dato es Optional<byte[]> imagen; [Editada]

Comment: ¿A qué se debe el fallo en el tipo de datos de variables?

Comment: En la línea salida.write(imagen); también me aparece ese error de tipo de dato. @E.Betanzos